# x86 code explained for small c program

Tags: c, x86, gdb

I have this simple C function:

```
void vulnerable(char *arg){
    char buf[100];
    strcpy(buf, arg);
}
```

When I disassemble it in GDB I get this:

```
0x08048ee0 <+0>:    push   %ebp
0x08048ee1 <+1>:    mov    %esp,%ebp
0x08048ee3 <+3>:    sub    $0x88,%esp
=> 0x08048ee9 <+9>: mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
0x08048eec <+12>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp)
0x08048ef0 <+16>:   lea    -0x6c(%ebp),%eax
0x08048ef3 <+19>:   mov    %eax,(%esp)
0x08048ef6 <+22>:   call   0x8048200
0x08048efb <+27>:   leave  
0x08048efc <+28>:   ret
```

I dont really understand these lines.

```
0x08048ee3 <+3>:    sub    $0x88,%esp  #why is 136 bytes being subtracted? Buf is only 100
0x08048ee9 <+9>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax  #I didnt think anything was in eax to move to ebp
0x08048eec <+12>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp) #whats being moved here
0x08048ef0 <+16>:   lea    -0x6c(%ebp),#eax #loading from the stack to ebp?
0x08048ef3 <+19>:   mov    %eax,(%esp) # now back to eax?
```

And I want to to know the address of buf. When I try `p &buf` it comes back with an address but its empty even if I break after the call line.

Can someone help me understand the code better.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
0x08048ee3 <+3>:    sub    $0x88,%esp  #why is 136 bytes being subtracted? Buf is only 100
```

`buf` is only 100 bytes long, but there's also space required on the stack for the two arguments to `strcpy()` - 4 bytes each so that's 108 bytes.  Add another 4 bytes to keep the stack pointer 8-byte aligned, and you get to 112.  That's still far short of the 136 bytes actually allocated by the compiler - likely the compiler has allocated stack space for some temporaries and/or saving registers, and then optimised out the actual temporaries and register spills.

```
0x08048ee9 <+9>:    mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax  #I didnt think anything was in eax to move to ebp
```

This is AT&T syntax, which has source followed by destination.  So this is moving `0x8(%ebp)`, which is the value of the first function argument `arg`, to `%eax`.

```
0x08048eec <+12>:   mov    %eax,0x4(%esp) #whats being moved here
```

The value of `arg` is then copied to the stack, as the second argument to `strcpy()`.

```
0x08048ef0 <+16>:   lea    -0x6c(%ebp),%eax #loading from the stack to ebp?
```

`lea` is load-effective-address.  This is loading the address of `-0x6c(%ebp)`, which is the local array `buf`, into `%eax`.

```
0x08048ef3 <+19>:   mov    %eax,(%esp) # now back to eax?
```

The address of `buf` is the copied from `%eax` to the stack, as the first argument to `strcpy()`.

Comment: Awesome thanks!! One quick question. When I do `x/2wx $esp` it prints out two addresses. Im assuming the second word is arg and the first is buf. Is that correct because buf is added to the stack second. @caf

Comment: @Kierchon: Yes, `buf` is at `(%esp)` and `arg` is at `4(%esp)`.